# Put Whole Original Document Under a new Property Name

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I created an aggregation pipeline which does the following:

1. Go to Custom collection and find by _id
2. Go to Default collection and find by id, attach it as Default
3. Go to Style collection and find by id, attach it as Style

Code:

```
Custom.aggregate([{
        $match: {
            '_id': mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.params.id)
        }
    },
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: 'styles',
            localField: 'styleId',
            foreignField: 'id',
            as: 'style'
        }
    },
    {
        $unwind: '$style'
    },
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: 'default',
            localField: 'styleId',
            foreignField: 'id',
            as: 'default'
        }
    },
    {
        $unwind: '$default'
    },
]).then(docs => res.json(docs))
}
```

This is the current output:

```
{
    "_id": "597774cc09064e2e4e9fedb7",
    "updatedAt": "2017-07-25T16:41:48.823Z",
    "createdAt": "2017-07-25T16:41:48.823Z",
    "styleId": "401648805",
    "colorId": null,
    "selectedOption": null,
    "deselectedOption": null,
    "currentOptions": [],
    "requiredItems": [],
    "includedItems": [],
    "furtherRemovals": [],
    "furtherAdditions": [],
    "excludedItems": [],
    "name": [],
    "__v": 0,
    "style": {
        "_id": "5902276effabb8bd2926be71",
        "id": "401648805",
        "name": "Luxury 4dr Sedan (2.0L 4cyl Turbo 8A)",
        "createdAt": "2017-07-26T15:28:36.778Z",
        "updatedAt": "2017-07-26T15:49:14.366Z"
    },
    "default": {
        "_id": "5978bfef32d246877e9cb363",
        "updatedAt": "2017-07-26T16:14:39.779Z",
        "createdAt": "2017-07-26T16:14:39.779Z",
        "id": "401648805",
        "requiredItems": [],
        "includedItems": [],
        "furtherRemovals": [],
        "furtherAdditions": [],
        "excludedItems": [],
        "__v": 0
    }
}
```

I am trying to wrap my Custom object in a "custom" named object, it better fits our data structure:

```
{
    "custom": {
        "_id": "597774cc09064e2e4e9fedb7",
        "updatedAt": "2017-07-25T16:41:48.823Z",
        "createdAt": "2017-07-25T16:41:48.823Z",
        "styleId": "401648805",
        "colorId": null,
        "selectedOption": null,
        "deselectedOption": null,
        "currentOptions": [],
        "requiredItems": [],
        "includedItems": [],
        "furtherRemovals": [],
        "furtherAdditions": [],
        "excludedItems": [],
        "name": [],
        "__v": 0,
    },
    "style": {
        "_id": "5902276effabb8bd2926be71",
        "id": "401648805",
        "name": "Luxury 4dr Sedan (2.0L 4cyl Turbo 8A)",
        "createdAt": "2017-07-26T15:28:36.778Z",
        "updatedAt": "2017-07-26T15:49:14.366Z"
    },
    "default": {
        "_id": "5978bfef32d246877e9cb363",
        "updatedAt": "2017-07-26T16:14:39.779Z",
        "createdAt": "2017-07-26T16:14:39.779Z",
        "id": "401648805",
        "requiredItems": [],
        "includedItems": [],
        "furtherRemovals": [],
        "furtherAdditions": [],
        "excludedItems": [],
        "__v": 0
    }
}
```

I think it has something to do with `$group` in the aggregation pipeline but I am not sure how to structure it. Any help would be greatly appreciated - relatively new to MonogoDB/Mongoose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally I would just [`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregationproject/) with `$$ROOT` to the new name "right at the start" of the pipeline after the [`$match`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/):

```
Custom.aggregate([
     { $match: {
       '_id': mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.params.id)
     }},
     { $project: { _id: 0, custom: '$$ROOT' } },
     { $lookup: {
       from: 'styles',
       localField: 'custom.styleId',
       foreignField: 'id',
       as: 'style'
     }},
     { $unwind: '$style' },
     { $lookup: {
       from: 'default',
       localField: 'custom.styleId',
       foreignField: 'id',
       as: 'default'
     }},
     { $unwind: '$default' }
]).then(docs => res.json(docs))
```

It's the least code and compatible with all versions since [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) was introduced.

Comment: This approach is better and simpler than I suggested.

Answer (score 1):

There might be a better way, but using [$replaceRoot](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/replaceRoot/) at the end of the pipeline should get you the required structure (untested):

```
Custom.aggregate([{
        $match: {
            '_id': mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.params.id)
        }
    },
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: 'styles',
            localField: 'styleId',
            foreignField: 'id',
            as: 'style'
        }
    },
    {
        $unwind: '$style'
    },
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: 'default',
            localField: 'styleId',
            foreignField: 'id',
            as: 'default'
        }
    },
    {
        $unwind: '$default'
    },

    {
        $replaceRoot: {
            newRoot: {
                "custom": {
                    "_id": "$_id",
                    "updatedAt": "$updatedAt",
                    "createdAt": "$createdAt",
                    "styleId": "$styleId",
                    "colorId": "$colorId",
                    "selectedOption": "$selectedOption",
                    "deselectedOption": "$deselectedOption",
                    "currentOptions": "$currentOptions",
                    "requiredItems": "$requiredItems",
                    "includedItems": "$includedItems",
                    "furtherRemovals": "$furtherRemovals",
                    "furtherAdditions": "$furtherAdditions",
                    "excludedItems": "$excludedItems",
                    "name": "$name",
                    "__v": "$__v",
                },
                "style": "$style",
                "default": "$default"

            }
        }
    }

]).then(docs => res.json(docs))
}
```

To use this feature your mongo version should be 3.4 or greater.

Comment: Why would you use an operator restricted to MongoDB 3.4 **and** make a very terse syntax that is not actually required? The way you are doing it is actually possible with a standard `$project` and does not require `$replaceRoot`, but there is also a **much more simplified** way.

Comment: @TalhaAwan thank you for your response. This has enabled Neil to deliver a response I desperately needed. Thank you for your push!